# how to deallocate heap memory in python

Tags: python, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am coming from C++ where I worked on heap memory and there I had to delete the memory of heap which I created on heap using 'new' keyword and I am always in confusion what to do in python for heap memory to stop memory leakage please recommend me any text for detail of python memory allocation and deletion.Thanks

Comment: Python has a *garbage collector*. So you do not need to do that.

Comment: Python is not C++. Python does everything for you.

Comment: Python is a high level language. And here you need not worry about memory de-allocation. It is the responsibility of the python runtime to manage memory allocations and de-allocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to do anything: Python first of all uses **reference counting**. This means that for every object it holds a counter that is incremented when you reference that object through a new variable, and decrements the counter in case you let the variable point to something else. In case the counter hits zero, then the object will be deleted (or scheduled for deletion).

This is not enough however, since two objects can reference each other and thus even if no other variable refer to the objects, these objects keep each other alive. For that, Python has an (optional) **garbage collector** that does cycle detection. In case such cycles are found, the objects are deleted. You can schedule such collection by calling `gc.collect()`.

In short: **Python takes care of memory management itself**. Of course it is your task to **make sure objects *can* be released**. For instance it is wise not to refer to a large object longer than necessary. You can do this for instance by using the `del` keyword:

```
foo = ... # some large object

# ...
# use foo for some tasks

del foo

# ...
# do some other tasks
```

by using `del` we have removed the `foo` variable, and thus we also decremented the counter refering to the object to which `foo` was refering. As a result, the object `foo` was refering too can be scheduled for removal (earlier). Of course compilers/interpreters can do liveness analysis, and perhaps find out themselves that you do not use `foo` anymore, but better be safe than sorry.

So in short: **Python manages memory itself by using reference counting and a garbage collector, the thing you have to worry about is that not that much objects are still "alive" if these are no longer necessary**.

Comment: Thanks Williem Van Onsem and please recommend a book to have full depth study on OOP of python.

Answer (score -3):

Python is a high level language. And here you need not worry about memory de-allocation. It is the responsibility of the python runtime to manage memory allocations and de-allocations.